# Painting single row in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to paint some single rows in a listview but I don't know how to do it. I only know how to change the background of the whole listview. My current code is this:

```
public void paintBackgroundRed(ArrayList<Integer> profileIngList, ArrayList<Integer> productIngList){
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_ingredients);

    for(int profileIng: profileIngList)
    {
        if (productIngList.contains(profileIng)){
            // paint int profileIng red
        }
    }
}
```

I have an hashmap so I can map the row to the profile ingredient ID. How can I paint the row that is commented? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing the color changing in your adapter. When you prepare the view (in getView), you can decide which color the background should be for the given element.